# Uploading an image file with NGINX takes a long time?

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to upload a simple .png image with gunicorn, nginx, flask, and MySQL, but a 5 mb image takes 10 seconds to upload? I am running a ec2 micro instance, but the CPU usage is less than 30% while uploading.

my flask code
        # post name uses unique ID for each image
        post_name = str(postID) + '_post.png'
        destination = os.path.join(target, post_name)

```
    c.execute('UPDATE posts set filename=%s, filetype="picture" 
         where postID=%s', 
              (destination, postID))

    file.save(destination)
```

my nginx config

```
location / {
    include proxy_params;
    client_max_body_size 250M;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    root /home/ubuntu ;
    client_body_buffer_size 8M;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before declaring upload to be slow, test somewhere else. EC2 bandwidth depends on instance size, and t2.micro doesn't have much. See https://cloudonaut.io/ec2-network-performance-cheat-sheet/